# Nifi Error: Failed to establish the connection with AMQP broker

Tags: hadoop, amqp, apache-nifi

I am trying to read the data from following cap files. 
everyhing from alerts folder

> http://dd2.weather.gc.ca/alerts/cap/20180205/CWHX/14/

I am using AMQP from http://metpx.sourceforge.net. And when I am trying to connect to subscriber from nifi, I am getting the following error.

> Failed to establish the connection with AMQP broker

this is my cap.conf file.

```
broker amqp://anonymous:anonymous@dd.weather.gc.ca
directory /data
subtopic alerts.cap.#
accept .*
mirror True
```

Answer (score 0):

- Over the summer, the broker migrated to SSL, so the current URL would be: amqps://anonymous:anonymous@dd.weather.gc.ca
- The web page has also moved to: https://github.com/MetPX/sarracenia
- best practice to put authentication info in ~/.config/sarra/credentials.conf
  a line like: amqps://anonymous:anonymous@dd.weather.gc.ca
- Installing a version from the past year is likely to be a much 
  better experience.  It now comes with sample configurations, 
  one of them being ddc_cap-xml.conf which is the same data you 
  are trying to download.

So the work is:

```
blacklab% sr_subscribe add ddc_cap-xml.conf
blacklab% sr_subscribe edit ddc_cap-xml.conf
# Change the directory option to suit your case.
blacklab% sr_subscribe foreground ddc_cap-xml.conf
```

And it should work.  It could take many hours to prove it because this particular set (severe weather warnings in Common Alerting Protocol format) is produced only when needed, rather than continuously.  (Use *start* instead of *foreground* to run as a background daemon.)

To test things, it might be easier to start with dd_swob, which will be a continuous feed.

```
blacklab% sr_subscribe list dd_swob

broker amqp://anonymous@dd.weather.gc.ca
exchange xpublic

#msg_skip_threshold 60
#on_msg ../msg_skip_old.py
subtopic observations.swob-ml.#

accept .*
```

In this configuration you need to add a *directory* option just before the *accept* line. and should start downloading data immediately. Once you know it works, switch back to the data set you actually want.